# Change mysql content type before query laravel

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a problem, I had this table (Pkb) :
[image]

It's basically a date (but in varchar format, YYYYMMDD), I want to select all the date before today using eloquent laravel 5

```
 $todays = Carbon::today();
 $filterdate = Pkb::whereDate('rtglb', '<=', $today)->get();
```

It works on result if used in controller but not with php artisan tinker (so basically it's not working and thrown an error) :
[image]

When I put it in handle function in command console, It's not working too because it's rtglb are in varchar table. (I need to put it in command console to create scheduller)

I have access to database, but I can't access the php code cause this table actually old module and I had to create new module that takes data from this table, calculate it using scheduller..

is there anyway to convert the content of rtglb to date before select it? using eloquent or raw mysql? or are there any solution for me?

Comment: What specifically is the error? Can you include the code in your console command?

Comment: Nothing happened, the code are not executed in handle function in console command. I check the error log nothing happened. Code in handle function in console command are same as above

Comment: Hmm. I hate to say that it's going to be quite hard for anyone here to help if you can't explain/demonstrate what's happening.

Comment: code in console command are same as above, nothing change. but if I change it to "Pkb::where('rtglb', '<=', #anynumber)->get();" the console command works and give result error are because rtglb are varchar not a date.

Comment: what's in $todays? If it's a regular date, e.g. `2016-09-14`, then what do you think will happen with `'2016-09-14' <= '2016011'`?

Comment: I test it with tinker and give this result http://prntscr.com/ci2n7p , any solution to convert rtglb content to date before I do the select where eloquent? after I have the $filterdate result I will calculate each data using foreach, and I have 10 thousand data to process...